# Unable to apply ngFor for jquery carousal

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using `jquery` carousal in my angular app, I am facing one issue i,e The carousal works fine fow for the `predefined data`,When i try to show the carousal with `dynamic data`, I am unable to show the dynamic data in the carousal.I am not familiar with `jquery`.Need help for this issue.Since component code is more i am giving this **[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-carousel-example-ehfbmo?file=app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: While it isn't a direct answer to your question, have you considered using an angular library rather than a jQuery library? It's often not considered the 'right way' to lean on jQuery libraries when things such as https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll will work without additional libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery is trying to render carousel with empty DOM which is **not rendered yet by Angular**.

You have to put your JQuery codes in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

...

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // Jquery code STARTS
    ...
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-carousel-example-pn1kjg

**NOTE**

Linking JavaScript files in `index.html` leads to make unable to reload automatically in Stackblitz and that is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It works fine for the predefined array `events[]`, but when i try to display the events from `api`, carousal doesn't work, I am calling the api inside `ngOnInit()` adn assigning object to `events[]` array. Is anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: @SGR In that case, I suggest you to move your JQuery codes to callback function in the API call.

Comment: Sorry i didn't  got it.

Comment: Now i am calling `api` in  `ngOnInit` like this ===>  `public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
     this.events = await this.myServices.allEvents();
   }`  then i am placing **jquery code** in `ngAfterViewInit` like this ====> `ngAfterViewInit(){
    // Jquery code STARTS
    ...
  }`

Comment: Move all codes inside `ngAfterViewInit` below `await this.myServices.allEvents();`

Comment: I have tried this also, but the content is coming one below the other, slider won't work.

Comment: I think it would be good to post another question with that API codes, then me or other SO user will help ;)

Comment: Okay i will POST

Comment: Can you please try in this link ==> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-carousel-example-pltk1f?file=app/app.component.html** I have called api with some dummly data.

Comment: Here the array name in `posts`

Comment: Would you post another question on Stackoverflow? It's hard to explain in comment and be helpful to other users.

Comment: I have posted the new question: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884169/not-able-to-display-dynamic-data-in-jquery-carousal** Please do check.